# multiple get observable requests in a for loop Angular2 Django

Tags: javascript, django, typescript, angular, rxjs

I am trying to perform several get requests using Angular2 in Django/python.

I am able perform an API request and get a list of users to find the id of the current user. I then perform a `.flatMap` operation to perform a second request to get a list of all comments. I compare the userId to the list of comments to select only the comments made by the user. All data I receive is JSON.

At this point, I am trying to get the Article that belongs to each comment made. But when I try to run a function to try to get data in a for loop, the request does not even get performed.

Heres my service:

```
import {Injectable} from "angular2/core";
import {Http, Headers, Response} from "angular2/http";
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  profileUserName: profileUserName = document.getElementsByClassName('profile-user-name')[0].children[0].innerHTML;
  userComments: [];

  constructor (private _http: Http) {}

  getUsers(): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.get('/api/v1/users/?format=json')
        .map((res: Response) => {
            this.userList = res.json();
            // select only comments made by current user
            for (i = 0; i < this.userList.length; i++) {
                if(this.profileUserName == this.userList[i].username){
                    this.userId = this.userList[i].url
                }
            }
        })
        .flatMap(() => this._http.get('/api/v1/article_comments/?format=json')).map((res: Response) => {
            this.commentList = res.json();
            let userComments = [];

            for (i = 0; i < this.commentList.length; i++) {
                if (this.commentList[i].user == this.userId) {
                    userComments.push(this.commentList[i])
                }
            }
            this.userComments = userComments;
            return this.parseArticleComments();
        })

  }

  parseArticleComments() {
    for (i = 0; i < this.userComments.length; i++) {
        this.currentSelection = this.userComments[i];
        this.getArticleComments(this.currentSelection)
    }
    // response should/is returned here to the appComponent
    return this.userComments
  }

  // currently not performing any http requests
  getArticleComments(currentSelection): Observable<any> {
    // currentselection.article == http://localhost:8000/api/v1/articles/10/?format=json
    return this._http.get('currentselection.article')
        .map((res: Response) => {
            console.log('entered');
            currentSelection.articles = res.json();
            return currentSelection.articles;
        })
  }
}
```

Heres my app.component:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {DataService} from './data.service.ts';

@Component({
  selector: 'http-app',
  template: `
    <div>
        <button (click)="logGetRequest()">Log Reqeust</button>
          <ul>
              <li *ngFor="let comment of commentList"> {{ comment.article }}  </li>
            </ul>
    </div>
  `,
  providers: [DataService]
})

export class AppComponent{
  commentList: string;

  constructor ( private _dataService: DataService) {}

  //get list of users to find user ID
  getUserList = this._dataService.getUsers()
    .subscribe(
        data => this.commentList = (data),
        error => console.error(error)
    );

  logGetRequest() {
    console.log(this.commentList);
  }
}
```

Any suggestions or ideas as to why I cannot perform these requests?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `parseArticleComments` method is asynchronous because it's based on the `getArticleComments` one. I would try something like that.

The `Observable.forkJoin` method wait for all observables to be execute (similar to `Promise.all`). The `Observable.of` method returns a raw observable for a specific value.

```
parseArticleComments() {
  var articleCommentsObservables = this.userComments.map(userComment => {
    return this.getArticleComments(userComment);
  });
  return Observable.forkJoin(articleCommentsObservables);
}
```

and call it into the callback of a flatMap operator:

```
.flatMap(() => this._http.get('/api/v1/article_comments/?format=json'))
.flatMap((res: Response) => {
  (...)
  return Observable.forkJoin([
    Observable.of(this.userComments),
    this.parseArticleComments()
  ]);
})
.map(result => {
  var userComments = result[0];
  return userComments;
})
```

Comment: I implemented your code exactly and assumed Observable.forJoin is forkJoin. But I still got an error. `TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined`. I also have `<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.17/Rx.js"></script>` included into my html file. Any ideas as to whats happening?